# run visual basic code with wamp server

Tags: mysql, vba, wamp

I have a WAMP server that is currently running.  There is another server that has an API using visual basic.  I can create the visual basic API query but what I need is for the script to run once or twice a day to get information and input that into my mySQL server.  I have very little experience with VBA mainly doing scripts for excel and coralDraw.

I need to figure out how to auto run a VB script on a WAMP server and put that information into a mySQL server.  If it is easier to so this just in windows and skip the wamp server then let me know.  I just need to get the information and put it into a database.

update: 12/18/12
Accessing the mysql through PHP is not the problem.  I have to access the information through a program on another server that has an API in VB.  Need to have a script run every midnight that will get the information from the API and put it into the mySQL database.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew. You can use PHP for a simple SQL query and you can run it with a Windows Scheduled task.

Answer (score 2):

Write simple PHP that adds data to your Database- WAMP supports php out of the box. If you understand VB logic, PHP is very similar and easy to use.

Simple example from [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm):

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO employee '.
       '(emp_name,emp_address, emp_salary, join_date) '.
       'VALUES ( "guest", "XYZ", 2000, NOW() )';

mysql_select_db('test_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but the problem is not connecting to the database.  The current system accesses it a lot through PHP.  My problem stems because I need to access another program on a server that uses an API in VB.  I need to figure out how to run the VB script and get the information back into the mySQL so my PHP site can use the information.

Comment: Well, in this case modify existing VB script that uses the API on the server and add MySQL connection- it will insert/update information to destination MySQL database directly. If MySQL database is not accessible from VB host computer, start using files--- copy required data to files (CSV, or XML) and save it to FTP; then write PHP script and parse those files. Or you can create an intermediate database (accessible from both machines) which you will use to save data to and update data from. There are many options.